# What is the correct (preffered) entry in SEF plugin for Site Domain

Tags: sef, system-plugin, metadata

Recently I found out that meta tag `rel="canonical"` is missing from my page source.
So I went to SEF plugin. It was published.
But the field 'Site Domain' was empty.
I entered `http://my-site.com` in the field and `rel=canonical` appeared in the source.
My question is: `http://my-site.com` or `http://www.my-site.com` here.

Domain is: `my-site.com`
*Use URL Rewriting* is ON and I have the following redirect in `.htaccess`:

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} !^(www\.my-site\.com)?$
RewriteRule (.*) http://www.my-site.com/$1 [R=301,L]
```

So, www or non-www version is better for this field?
Or not to use this field at all? Site is well indexed by Google even without `rel=canonical`.
Joomla! 3.6.4

Answer (score 1):

That question has been asked so many times and created very long arguments that were never won by anyone.

My thought: Take a look at google's website, and see if they use www, and do what they're doing, since they are doing what they think is right, and, as a site administrator, you should only care about their opinion.

Note: They use www on google.com, google.ca, and every other google in the world.

Comment: I'm not so proficient in redirecting and server administration, but I need to care of it also. And yes, I'm going to read https://support.google.com/webmasters/answer/93633. Google appears with www, my site also. But I do not know how they set's their servers and what kind of redirects they use. Also it would be good if Google runs at least one site with Joomla :)

Answer (score 0):

I think you can choose both, but read previously https://support.google.com/webmasters/answer/139066?hl=en

Better setting to 
`https://www.my-site.com` instead of http if your website supports https.